# How to make Java "trust" an expired certificate?

Tags: java, certificate, java-web-start

I have a CA-signed, but long expired code signing certificate in use for a JWS-deployed web application.

When I launch this app, I get a warning prompt asking whether I trust this publisher. When I agree, in Java control panel I can see the certificate in Security tab.

How can I achieve the same effect programmatically (from command line)? `keytool -import` does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: What kind of error message does keytool display on import?

Comment: It doesn't fail to import, but it seems I am not importing it to the right keystore because it has no effect. What is the default (system) keystore that works for all users?

Comment: @Konrad:The default truststore for java is the `cacerts` keystore.

Answer (score 2):

The portecle program is a great little tool for doing things which you can otherwise only do using the API. You can get it here: http://portecle.sourceforge.net/

On Windows Vista/7 you must run the program as administrator if you want to import a certificate into cacerts. I do this by running command prompt as administrator, then running the portecle.bat file.

The cacerts file is located here: 
$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts

Press CTRL-O to open a keystore file. The password for cacerts is changeit

Don't forget to save after you import your certificate.